# The correct usage of "of" and "about" with an adjective

Tags: grammar, adjectives

In a sentence, Why do we use "Proud of" and not "Proud about". This is in contrast with the usage "Sad about". Why is the usage different for Sad and Proud, when they are indeed both adjectives in this context?

Comment: Different adjectives use different collocations. _Why_ is not necessarily a useful question to ask about such differences. Why would you want to use _proud about_, and not _proud for_, since we do say _I'm happy for you_, and _happy_ is also an adjective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soup, at [UsingEnglish.com_Forum](https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/94475-Why-adjectives-can-have-a-prepositional-phrase-after-them), addresses the question of the use of prepositions after adjectives:

> Certain adjectives and past participles used as adjectives can be
>   followed by a preposition + noun / gerund. Usually specific adjectives
>   and participles require specific prepositions. These can be found by
>   consulting a good dictionary, which after any adjective will give the
>   prepositions that can be used with it. §*about, at, for, in, of,
>   on, to*, and *with* are the most commonly used prepositions with
>   adjectives and participles.
>
> There are no specific rules for which preposition to use with which
>   adjective but learning them as you would learn a new vocabulary word
>   seems to help most people. However, the rule for what kind of
>   complement should follow the preposition can be deduced through the
>   examples that accompany each adjective/preposition combination.

A link to a list of commonly used combinations provided by Universidad Panamericana is given, but I can't duplicate it here. [Here is one provided by Bedavaingilizce.com](https://www.bedavaingilizce.com/prepositions/adj_pre.htm), but it is not exhaustive: it lists neither all adjectives which may be followed by a prepositional phrase, nor all prepositions which may follow a given adjective.

In [this Quora article](https://www.quora.com/Proud-of-vs-proud-about-Which-one-is-the-correct-usage), Brett Reynolds states that 'proud about' is not ungrammatical, but is used far less frequently than 'proud of'. I agree. [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nothing+to+be+proud+about%2Cnothing+to+be+proud+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnothing%20to%20be%20proud%20about%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnothing%20to%20be%20proud%20of%3B%2Cc0) show that '... nothing to be proud about' is sometimes chosen.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. Although, the Quora community seems to be kind of ambiguous about "Proud About/of" and it seems like "Proud of" just became more popular with usage.

Comment: That's how language normally develops. Grammar czars are rare and unpopular.